# reading the bean definition from xml file Spring

Tags: java, spring

While reading the bean definition from an xml file, which of the below two methods is best. I remember reading about `Resource` , that using this is fast or something like that but don't know exactly.

```
Resource rs = new ClassPathResource("hello.xml");
BeanFactory  factory = new XmlBeanFactory(rs);
```

or

```
BeanFactory  factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileInputStream("myBean.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to prefer http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html directly just because this class implements BeanFactory interface and has much more goodies.